# $get() and $find() with AJAX.NET

Tags: ajax.net

I'm trying to follow the PageMethods example found [here](http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/).
However, I get an error when trying to call `$get('Label1')`.
  Since, Label1 is an asp:Label, it works if I call $get() with the ClientID.   Yet, the example is using the actual ID. Is there a way to use $get() with the actual ID?

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends what the label is contained in. In some controls it will be Label1 and work, in others it won't be. Don't chance it.

So on a simple page it gets rendered as Label1:

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="test" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
```

On a more complex page it will be rendered as something else (ctl00_head_Label1 in my case), using a masterpage as an example:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="test" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```