# Inserting value to AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm using `AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor`, and I want to add a value to it using JavaScript or jQuery like this:

```
alert( $find("eCompose_ctl02_ctl01")); // if 

$find("eCompose_ctl02_ctl01").attr('value') = "asdfasdfasdf  asdfasd asdf sf";
```

also tried like this:

```
document.getElementById('eCompose_ctl02_ctl01').value += "ababsakas asdasd l";
```

But the above code does not insert text into HTMLEditor.
Can anyone help me?

EDIT
This is the HTML code for HTMLEditor:

```
<HTMLEditor:Editor ID="eCompose" runat="server" Height="240px" Width="90%" AutoFocus="true" InitialCleanUp="true" />
```

I tried to access like this:

```
alert(document.getElementById("<%= eCompose.ClientID %>"))
```

and got `null`.

Comment: May I ask how this is related to jQuery?

Comment: I deleted those tags, it is not related to jQuery, we are talking about methods of the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit.

Comment: Out of interest, you didn't accept answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099370/how-do-i-show-keywords-and-a-search-box-under-my-sites-google-results or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003649/website-webservice-to-fetch-data-from-pc or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394262/how-to-play-mp4-video-on-window-webserver-in-quick-time-and-flash-playerflv-play. Were they not helpful? You also duplicated this question, incorrectly tagged, and are now including detail in the comments. Suggest you read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq section titled: "How do I ask questions here?"

Comment: yeah James you are right... i read the faqs..

Comment: Did you find the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be confusing AJAX.NET and jQuery.

`attr()` is a valid jQuery function, but am not so sure it is AJAX.NET. `$find()` is AJAX.NET, whereas `$()` is jQuery.

Does yor item `eCompose_ctl02_ctl01` have a ClientID? I.e what does the rendered HTML look like? Check out [$get() and $find() with AJAX.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982662/get-and-find-with-ajax-net) for this sort of issue.

Also, what does the alert give you?

Give us some more info, e.g. HTML.

Comment: HTMLEditor basically places an iframe, inside that its main TextEditor is loaded. and below the iframe there is a textarea, and i think the textarea is hidden at first time,  textarea become visible when HTMLeditor iframe fails to load.
And i was using the textarea id (eCompose_ctl02_ctl01) to insert a value... and it was happenning nothing because textarea was hidden due to the successfully loading of main HTMLeditor...

Comment: But now how to insert text in the HTMLEditor using javascript, 
I am working on a forum. below the HTMLEditor there are similies(images/icons), if a user clicks on a simily then its id is inserted into the editor where the I beam is...

Comment: The way to insert text with javascript is the method ("set_content"), as I explain to you in my answer.

Comment: yes i agree to you: but the prob is how to identify the HTMLEditor, as we do other html element like this: document.getElementId('')

Comment: this is html code for HTMLEditor:                                         <HTMLEditor:Editor ID="eCompose" runat="server" Height="240px" Width="90%" AutoFocus="true" InitialCleanUp="true" />      i tried to access like this:                 alert(document.getElementById("<%= eCompose.ClientID %>"));

Comment: Before that i was using FreeTextEditor, and it was working fine with-document.getElementById('').value = "asdfasd"

Comment: you have to use $find("<%=eCompose.ClientID%>").set_content("whatever"), and alert( $find("<%=eCompose.ClientID%>").get_content());

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it using the Ajax methods that .NET provides is:

```
$find("NAME_OF_THE_CONTROL").set_content("Hello world");
```

`"NAME_OF_THE_CONTROL"` is the `ClientID` of your control, I suppose in this case, `eCompose_ctl02_ctl01`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the way to insert text with javascript is the method ("set_content"), I would say it's a copy of Tinymce.

Comment: you have to use $find("<%=eCompose.ClientID%>").set_content("whatever"), and alert( $find("<%=eCompose.ClientID%>").get_content());

Comment: It's strange. If you go here http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/OtherSamples/ClientSide.htm, using the script tab of firebug, and using this method, $find("editor).set_content("whatever"), this works.

Comment: yes i have checked but my page source is similar to this page:         http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/OtherSamples/FullScreen.aspx